# Module not found in virtual environment: Pandas

Tags: python3, odoo, pandas

I am running Ubuntu 20.04. I have create a virtual environment to run Odoo. In activating an app it returned an error saying `ModuleNotFound: pandas`. Pandas is installed globally. Can I install this only in the venv? Should I even want to do that? What's the best way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Python modules installed globally are by default not installed into a venv. This default behavior when creating a venv can be overwritten, but most of the times you want to start with a clean / empty venv.

You can install pandas (or any other module) in the venv without conflicting the globally installed version. Simply change to the venv, activate it, and run `pip3 install NAME_OF_THE_PYTHON_MODULE_TO_INSTALL`.

It is generally considered a good practice to install Python modules via pip on a per-user base or within a venv if you want to have or need a clean environment for your project.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that. I was getting a message that basically said the requirements are already met. 

I did figure out a workable solution though - I copied an existing instance of pandas into the /site-packages for my venv.

Thank you.